# Name of a Sample Graph

Tags: data-visualization, barplot

I wanted to make a graph for my data which looks something like this (This sample image is taken from Google):

[image: This sample image is taken from Google]

But, I am not able to search what is the name of this graph which shows frequencies on the X-axis or what is it called?

Comment: The x axis shows *category labels.*  The counts (or frequencies) are shown on the y axis.  In general, by googling "statistical graphics gallery" you can find examples of many graphics with common names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all: it's just a [barplot](https://www.statmethods.net/graphs/bar.html) (or *barchart*) with an additional feature. I personally prefer to put the frequencies inside the bars.

To recreate your data, I use:

```
mydata <- c(rep("USA", 11), "Russia", "China", "India")
```

Then to create an R equivalent of your plot:

```
frequencies <- sort(table(mydata), decreasing = TRUE)

bp <- barplot(frequencies          # bp contains the central x-coords of the bars
             , main = "Aircraft Carriers" # title
             , xlab = "Country"    # x-axis label
             , ylab = "Number")    # y-axis label

text(  x = bp                # x-coords of the labels
     , y = frequencies       # y-coords of the labels (change this is you need to)
     , labels = frequencies  # the frequencies are the labels
     , pos = 1)              # put text below the x,y-coordinates
```

To produce:

[image: Aircraft carriers per country.]

Answer (score 1):

It is a column chart with data table.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Can it be generated using SPSS or R?

Comment: I have not done it personally. Try this https://learnr.wordpress.com/2009/04/29/ggplot2-labelling-data-series-and-adding-a-data-table/